# Como eu posso imputar valores com o Sublime text

Tags: python, sublime-text

Como eu posso passar valores para o Sublime Text
exp: criei esse simples programa para poder fazer uma conta basica!
Obs:não tem caixa para passar valor, eu acredito que precisa usar o terminal mais não sei muito bem

```
a = input('digite o primeiro valor ')
b = input('digite o segundo valor')
print('o valor do primeiro é:{} e o segundo é:{}'.format(a,b))
```

Comment: Ja tentou usar a janela do console do próprio editor?  Eu precisei fazer um plugin uma vez, mas era pra trocar os parametros da linha de comando, mas acredito que pra input o console talvez resolva. Mais tarde, se der, testo e comento aqui.

Comment: Tem [esse pacote](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL), que parece ser o que vc precisa. Embora nesse caso eu prefira rodar no terminal mesmo, mas a "filosofia" do Sublime parece ser a de instalar pacotes pra tudo (até o gerenciador de pacotes é um pacote que tem que ser instalado à parte...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce consegue rodar pelo próprio Sublime.
Basta salvar seu projeto e apertar "ctrl"+"B" (Ou 'Tools', 'Build') para rodar o projeto.
No Sublime, voce poderá utilizar o terminal próprio (que geralmente fica na parte de baixo da IDE).
Lembre-se de colocar  "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" no início do seu código, para aceitar os caracteres especiais (com acentuação).

Caso queira utilizar pelo terminal, depende se seu SO for Windows ou Linux:
No geral:

- Verifique se o python está na path (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages);
- Salve seu arquivo com a extenção .py. (exemplo teste.py).
- No terminal, navegue até a pasta onde está o arquivo. Digite:
  "python teste.py".
  Se não tiver nenhum erro, você poderá fazer input pelo terminal.

Comment: Nota: O `coding: utf-8` no início do arquivo era necessário apenas no Python 2. Na versão 3 os arquivos já são por padrão em UTF-8.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda